# Implementing lists in a for loop in R to produce a table of column names and datatypes from multiple dbfs

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I’m trying to extract the column names and associated datatypes from a number of dbfs and put the results into a table to cross reference which column names and datatypes appear in which dbfs. I’ve written an initial R script for this as a trial using just two dbfs and it works fine. The problem is when I try to adapt the script to iterate over many dbfs I can’t quite get the result right.

The script for two dbfs is:

```
library(foreign)
dbf05 <- read.dbf("path/data05.dbf")
dbf06 <- read.dbf("path/data06.dbf")

dbf05ColnamesDT <- lapply(dbf05,class)
dbf06ColnamesDT <- lapply(dbf06,class)
ColnamesDTList <- list(dbf05ColnamesDT, dbf06ColnamesDT)

maxLength <- max(lengths(ColnamesDTList)) #Get the max length of the lists in ColnamesDTList

#Create a df from the nested list, with equal length columns
ColnamesDTDf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(ColnamesDTList, `length<-`, maxLength)))

#Rename rows
years <- 2005:2006
new.names <-NULL
for(i in 1:2){
  new.names[i]<-paste("dbf", years[i], sep="")
}
row.names(ColnamesDTDf)<-new.names
```

This produces a table like this, which is exactly what I want:

```
        cname1  cname2  cname3  cname4  cname5  cname6  
dbf2005 factor  factor  numeric numeric factor  factor  
dbf2006 numeric factor  numeric factor  numeric NULL
```

The script I have for the iteration is:

```
library(foreign)
files <- list.files("path/", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.dbf$") #List files

BBcolnamesDTList <- list()
for (i in 1:14){
  dbfs <- read.dbf(files[i])
  ColnamesDT <- lapply(dbfs,class)
  ColnamesDTList[[i]] <- list(ColnamesDT)
}

maxLength <- max(lengths(ColnamesDTList))
ColnamesDTDf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(ColnamesDTList, `length<-`, maxLength)))

years <- 2005:2018
new.names <-NULL
for(i in 1:14){
  new.names[i]<-paste("dbf", years[i], sep="")
}
row.names(ColnamesDTDf)<-new.names
```

This produces a table with only one column containing the list of column names:

```
        V1
dbf2005 list(cname1 = “factor”, cname2 = “factor”, cname3 = “numeric”, …        
dbf2006 list(cname1 = “numeric”, cname3 = “factor”, cname4 = “numeric”,…
```

In addition, ‘’’maxLength’’’ returns 34 in the first script but only 1 in the iterative script, which tells me that the list structure I have in the for loop is incorrect but I’m not sure how to implement it correctly.

Comment: One problem seems to be that you do `ColnamesDTList[[i]] <- list(ColnamesDT)` in the first `for`-loop. `lapply` already returns a list that you stored in `ColnamesDT`, so `list(ColnamesDT)` creates a list around it wherein `ColnamesDT` is one element. That is also the reason why you get `maxLength=1`. Solution: Just leave out `list()` and do `ColnamesDTList[[i]] <- ColnamesDT` instead. I am not sure whether this solves everything, though.

Comment: Thanks @benimwolfspelz. That worked great. I now have a follow up issue which I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589397/how-to-reproduce-all-column-names-when-producing-a-table-to-cross-reference-colu